# Pipe doesn't return value when using observabe inside it

Tags: angular, pipe, angular6, observable

I am using the pipe to get data from store ( Redux status management) and do some processing using this data and add some markups and return the new.
In html I am receiving this value and render it. 
Once I start using the store and use the observable pattern to get data from store, I cannot receive any data on the html template.
When I print the value iside the pipe ( exactly before the return), it show the data, but it doesn't reflect on the html element.

here is the code inside the tranform function

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'highlight',
})
export class HighlightSearchPipe implements PipeTransform {


constructor(private store: Store<any>, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) 
{}

transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
this.store
  .select(currentSearchQuerySelector)
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
  )
  .subscribe(processedSearchText => {
    processedSearchText.forEach(searchText => {
      const re = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');
      const match = value.match(re);
      // If there's no match, just return the original value.
      if (!match) {
        return value;
      }

      value = value.replace(re, '<mark class="saqr-first-mark">' + match[0] + '</mark>');
    });
    console.log(value);  //print the right values
    return value;
  });
 }
}
```

and here is the html code

```
 <span class="m-widget3__username" [innerHTML]="user.name | highlight | async">
```

Comment: This code does not show how those 2 snippets are related.

Comment: Ok I will post the full cod of the pipe

Comment: You are returning in subscribe callbac. Subscribe callbacks does not have return values.

Comment: I tried to remove the return statement, same thing, nothing render on the html.

Comment: My recommendation: invert your idea. Go for something like `processedSearchText$ | async | hightlight:user.name`

Comment: Handling asynchronous/stream logic in a pipe will make it impure, thus increasing its complexity

Comment: Why are you querying store in pipe instead of taking string as input, mutate and return is a good question.

Comment: This was my first attempt, but it shows that it keeps processing the words to be highlighted each time the pipe is called, so much work is repeated, this is why I process the words once and store it in the store and get it in the pipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to return in subscription callback which is invalid. What you want to do here (probably) is to return `Observable` so your `async` can subscribe to it.

```
return this.store
  .select(currentSearchQuerySelector)
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
    map(processedSearchText => {
    processedSearchText.forEach(searchText => {
      const re = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');
      const match = value.match(re);
      // If there's no match, just return the original value.
      if (!match) {
        return value;
      }

      value = value.replace(re, '<mark class="saqr-first-mark">' + match[0] + '</mark>');
    });
    console.log(value);  //print the right values
    return value;
  })
 });
```

Obviously brackets might be wrong as I edited your snippet, but you should get the idea and adjust it to be syntaticly valid with  your IDE.

Comment: I tried this way as well, but it prints [object Object]

Comment: in the console.log it prints the full statement of the value after the edit, how can I reach it out in the html? it prints object there?

Comment: Show me whats in the console

Comment: It's just a text `Doha Forum`

Comment: I was making a simple mistake, but this code is WORKING. thank you